# Possible to choose Screenshot output method with Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: screen-capture

The revised Screenshot utility in Mojave brings the handy option of choosing if the resulting Screenshot should be copied to the clipboard or saved as a file, or saved to email, etc.

However this requires that I first press Cmd+Shift+5 to bring up the options, then select my desired option using the pointer. I find myself often needing to switch between saving to a file and saving to the clipboard and wondering if there is a way to do this by a keyboard command or modifier.

For example it would be great if I could use Cmd+Shift+4 to capture a selection, but modify the command to save-to-clipboard or save-to-file.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already there…

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots

By default
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  will save as a file
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>    <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  will save to clipboard.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!  I didn't think to look in the Shortcuts. Of course this assumes that the Options in Cmd+Shift+5 are set to something other than "Clipboard".